# Mercurial: How do I find out the difference between my working copy and another copy

Tags: mercurial

I am new to Mercurial and mostly worked on Clearcase.

Before I pull in changes from the latest branch, I would like to know the changes that are there and which files have conflicts. (Mainly to see if I should do a update now or later.)

Is there any way do do a hg diff between a working copy and another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check what changes are in the other repository using:

```
hg incoming path
```

This is basically like `pull`, however it doesn’t actually pull.

But actually, you can usually just pull, because pulling incoming changesets doesn’t touch your working copy. Only when you `update` or `merge` does your working copy get updated, with a risk for conflicts.

Ideally there would be an option on `update` and `merge` to do a tentative merge, that is, it would merge unless there is a conflict, but afaik such an option currently does not exist yet.

Once the changes are pulled into your repository though, you can use diff to compare it with your working copy as usual.

```
hg diff -r tip
```

Answer (score 2):

> s there any way do do a hg diff between a working copy and a another ?

No. diff compares **two revisions from repo**. In you case you can blindly pull (get updatesto repo), but avoid automatic update|merge of your working copy. With synced repo you can use hg diff, hg update, hg merge by hand when and if it's needed. You can also do nothing and commit your changes - you'll have anonymous branch only and additional head in repo

Comment: You could use another tool like WinMerge to recursively compare folders

Answer (score 2):

In first place, you should commit your changes before doing anything. I never worked with ClearCase, but I think it must work like SVN, forgive me if I'm wrong. One of the greatest advantages of DVCS over CVCS is that it allows you to *commit first* and decide what to do later. That's very important because you consolidate your work first, if things start to get too messy in the merge later, your work is safe in the repository. In the worse cenario you can even abandon the messy merge and start all over again. And even after the merge, the version of your original work (before the merge) will be there, very important to check if that merge introduced some problem. In SVN (and assuming ClearCase is similar) it's the opposite: it doesn't allow a commit without an update and merge... I hate it!

Another thing, the pull command in mercurial doesn't change anything in the working directory. It just brings the changes to the local repository. So, in my oppinion, you should:

1. Commit
2. Pull, nothing will happen with the working copy
3. Now you can check the log, compare the revisions and decide what and how to do with no risk of loosing your work. If you decide that you won't merge now, that's fine, you don't have to merge things just because you pulled other revisions (although the recommended practice is to merge often to avoid headaches merging very different revisions)

Comment: Though I agree that it would be best to commit, often you have a lot of debug code that you are not ready to do so. (Maybe that whole thought process has to change with 'merge often'). Your advice is good but does not solve what I am really looking for.

Comment: patch queues are really useful for debug code. Put it in a patch, pop it when you want to go  back to a clean repo, push it back on when you need it again.

Comment: @TheVyom, having a lot of debug code is not a reason to avoid commit. Commit is a local operation, it affects only your local repository. That's the great thing about DVCS, you don't need to have a fully tested-working code to commit, you should commit far more often. In a later stage, when you think the code is ready, you push or merge the whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using TortoiseHG then you can use the incoming button which downloads the incoming changesets but gives you the choice to apply them or not.

[See here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/0.9/changelog.html#sync-bar).